# Proofs that include long terms

Tags: proof-writing

While writing a proof that included expansion of $(\sqrt{n} + 1)^8$ in which I know the first term has to be $n^4$, is it acceptable to write something like $(n^4 +...... + 1)$ if the $n^4$ is the only thing I really need to move progress further in the proof?

Comment: Without more context, yes...

Comment: That would be generally acceptable as long as you give a rationale, for example `using the binomial expansion ...`. Maybe also fix that `8` at the end while at it.

Comment: The $+8$ at the end should be $+1$.  If you want to draw attention to the fact that all terms are smaller you could write $n^4+o(n^4)$

Comment: The next term is $8n^{7/2}$

Comment: It's probably a bad idea, it looks like short for $n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1$.  Why not just say "Let $(\sqrt n+1)^8=n^4+a$ for some $a$" and then you can just use $a$ unambiguously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's fine. Remember that you're allowed to use words in proofs; feel free to use as many as necessary in order to be clear. Maybe the following would be a good example:

> Consider the binomial expansion of $(\sqrt{n} + 1)^8$, where the first term is $n^4$. So take $(n^4 + \ldots + 1)$ and (...your next steps here)